# How will i show my data output inside an input element using Jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Here is my Javascript code:

```js
$('#sb_add_ctrl').click(function() {

    var value = $('#sel_control_num').val();
    for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) {

        value = value.replace(/(\d+)$/, function(match, n) {
            const nextValue = ++match;
            return ('0' + nextValue).slice(1);
        });

        $('#parent')[0].innerHTML += '<br>' + value;

    }
})
```

Here is my HTML code:

```
 <div><label> Control Number </label>
      <input name="get_control_num" style="text-transform:uppercase"
       class="form-control" id="sel_control_num" readonly>
 </div> 

 <div class="form-group">
    <label> Quantity </label>
         <input class="form-control" name="quantity" type="number"
          />
         <br>
         <button type="button" id="sb_add_ctrl" class="btn btn-primary"> Add   
    Control Number </button>
  </div>
    
 <div class="form-group" id="parent"></div>
```

What I want to do is get the existing class of the input and show the data that is in innerHTML into an input element .I can't think of a proper solution cause I am still a beginner in javascript/jquery, I tried the other methods in jquery but still it doesn't work thanks for the help[image]

Comment: where is `sel_control_num` ? Also which input field you are taking about ?

Comment: I'm sorry I just edited my post,  the input field should be auto generated inside the div which the id of it is "parent", is it possible? or should I make an input element where it has an another ID on it? thanks for the help!

Comment: So you need to show `GTX-3071,GTX-3072..` in separate input box ? If yes why not simply do :  `$('#parent')[0].innerHTML += '<br><input type="text" value="'+value+'">';` .

Comment: I didn't thought this was the code line. I tried methods just to get what is inside and then wrapped it that is why it is not showing. Thank you ver much!